# Custom spaces editable from back office in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, placeholder

I've got a website in Drupal where in some parts of the site I need some editable spaces to put some banners and edit them from backoffice, (something similar to placeholders in Django).

Is there any module or a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is the block module, which is part of core. Are you using Drupal 6/7/8?
Anyway go into your admin section and look under structure, for blocks.
You can create custom blocks and place them in a region. If you want different regions then you can define these in your themes .info file.

Inside the blocks you can put whatever content you like.

Comment: Thank you, Drupal 6.x. I've created a block and a region (custom_banners) to print the block in a specific part of the site. And in my home.tpl.php I have <?php print $custom_banners; ?>, but I can't see what I wrote in the block. Do I need to do something else??

Comment: I don't think you should use that variable, instead just $content. Note the render function also... not too sure about 6 but look at other tpl.php files for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Than you for your help , this did the job:

< ? php

$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', "23(block number)");

print $block['content'];

? >

Answer (score 0):

So, to create a custom (static) block you should go to "Blocks" admin page (Structure -> Blocks) and click "add block page" link. When creating the block pay attention on input format field (bellow "block body" field). If you use some format with filters drupal can (partially) destroy your block code - filter out some content. So, if you are sure that code you are using is safe and don't want it to be changed by drupal select "raw" format.

Every theme has defined regions that it supports. They are defined in:

```
/sites/all/themes/theme-name/theme-name.info file
```

So, if you want to change page template and print blocks on your own you must use some existing regions, defined there (it's needed to clear the cache after changing this file).
Region names can also be seen in Blocks admin page mentioned above. On that page you'll see the list of all available blocks and next to block name you'll see drop-down for placing block into some region.

Also, if you edit some block (click "configure" link next to that drop-down) you'll have some extra options to set block visibility (per user, per user role, per page..).

For more advanced block placement use "Context" module which have more powerful features for placing blocks and more:

https://www.drupal.org/project/context